# How to populate histogram in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table containing a field of type DATETIME. I need to generate a histogram of record counts based on hour of day. I use following query to get the histogram:

```
select HOUR(date) AS `hour`, count(*) as count from records group by hour(date);
```

results:

```
+ --------- + ---------- +
| 5         | 7          |
| 9         | 10         |
| 10        | 2131       |
| 12        | 14         |
+ --------- + ---------- +
4 rows
```

So, there is 7 records between 05:00:00 and 05:59:59 in all dates, and so on. But there is no record at 06 AM. I want to have all values between 00 and 23 in result with values of 0:

```
+ --------- + ---------- +
| 0         | 0          |
| 1         | 0          |
| 2         | 0          |
| 3         | 0          |
| 4         | 0          |
| 5         | 7          |
| 6         | 0          |
| 7         | 0          |
          .....
24 rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50fa4/16

```
select HOUR(date) AS `hour`, 
count(*) - 1 as count 
from 
(select * 
 from records
union
select "2008-01-19 01:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 02:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 03:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 04:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 05:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 06:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 07:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 08:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 09:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 10:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 11:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 12:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 13:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 14:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 15:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 16:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 17:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 18:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 19:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 20:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 21:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 22:14:07", 0
union
select "2008-01-19 23:14:07", 0) as b
group by hour(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done a lot of histogram query like yours and the only way I've found so far without TEMPORARY was to do a foreach on the result array and complet it with missing value.

here an exemple in php.
Please note that you have to adapte the request to your code

```
    //query my db and return an array with values only on hour that have a value
    $query = 'SELECT HOUR(date) AS `hour`, count(*) as count FROM records GROUP BY HOUR(date)';

    //PDO stuff
    $query->execute();
    $queryResult = $query->fetchall();

    print_r($queryResult);
    // Array ( [0] => Array ( [hour] => 6 [count] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [hour] => 7 [count] => 1 ))


    $H24 = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23);

    //foreach on the queryResult and add missing hour with a default value
    foreach ($H24 as $key=>$hour) {
      if(!in_array($hour, $queryResult))
        array_push($queryResult, array('hour' => $hour, 'count' => '0'));
      }

    //at this point $quertResult now have a value for each hour

    print_r($queryResult);
    //Array ( [0] => Array ( [hour] => 0 [count] => 0 ) [1] => Array ( [hour] => 1 [count] => 1 ... [x] => Array ( [hour] => 23 [count] => 0 ))
```

hope it help